# Increment counter with Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have seen an increment counter with Cloud Functions referencing Realtime Database, but not Firebase Firestore yet.

I have a cloud function that listens for new documents:

```
exports.addToChainCount = functions.firestore
    .document('chains/{name}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

    // Initialize document
    var chainCounterRef = db.collection('counters').doc('chains');

    var transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {
        return t.get(chainCounterRef).then(doc => {
            // Add to the chain count
            var newCount = doc.data().count + 1;
            t.update(chainCounterRef, { count: newCount });
        });
    }).then(result => {
        console.log('Transaction success!');
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
    });
    return true;
});
```

I'm attempting the above transaction, but when I run `firebase deploy` in terminal I get this error:

> error  Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
>   functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

This is my first attempt at anything node.js, and I'm not sure I've written this right.

Comment: There is a whole page of documentation describing sharded counters with Firestore.  The reason why you need to shard in many production cases is because Firestore documents can only process one write per second under load.  Anything more under load and you will lose writes, and your count will become inaccurate.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks, but I want to increment my counter using cloud functions. Are you suggesting this is not recommended?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you write your documents.  The limit stands.

Comment: @DougStevenson Is there any way to control the rate at which cloud functions are triggered by new documents?  If so, it would be possible to update a counter using a queuing system as described in the original post. It would occasionally get backed up, but the rate-limiting would prevent Firestore from getting overloaded.

Comment: @DerrickMiller What you're asking is far more complex than could be addressed in a SO comment.  Such as thing is not built into the product.

Comment: OK :-(  Thanks for the info @DougStevenson!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is now a much simpler way to increment/decrement a field in a document: `FieldValue.increment()`. Your sample would be something like this:

```
const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;
var chainCounterRef = db.collection('counters').doc('chains');
chainCounterRef.update({ count: FieldValue.increment(1) });
```

See:

- [Incrementing Values Atomically with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html)

Comment: Best, most up to date solution.

Comment: Yes, this should be the accepted answer. This new addition helps to keep metadata about a collection in a document. Very handy indeed! Good answer.

Comment: Does this works only for Cloud Firestore or also for Realtime Database?

Comment: This answer is for Cloud Firestore, but a few months ago Realtime Database also added support for an atomic increment operator: `ServerValue.increment(1)`. If you're having trouble making it work, please post a new question with the minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Yet another, great and simplest solution, @FrankvanPuffelen. Had to add `const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;` to make it work.

Comment: Using chainCounterRef.set({ count: FieldValue.increment(1) }); to make it work when document don't exist.

Comment: This doesnt work properly if you have multiple instances of that function being run and you are using the value. For example, if you using it to increment an invoice number, there are times when you get duplicates.

Comment: `increment` does not depend on the current value that exists in your application code, so the number of instances should not matter. If you're having a problem making `increment` work for you, I recommend posting a new question with a [minimal reproduction](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can have a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to safely increment a number in a document, you can use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions).  The following code is taken directly from the linked page.  It adds one to a field called `population` in a document `/cities/SF` after giving it some initial values:

```
// Initialize document
var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('SF');
var setCity = cityRef.set({
  name: 'San Francisco',
  state: 'CA',
  country: 'USA',
  capital: false,
  population: 860000
});

var transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {
  return t.get(cityRef)
      .then(doc => {
        // Add one person to the city population
        var newPopulation = doc.data().population + 1;
        t.update(cityRef, { population: newPopulation });
      });
}).then(result => {
  console.log('Transaction success!');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
});
```

Bear in mind that Firestore is limited to one write per second under sustained load, so if you're going to be writing a lot, you will need to use a [sharded counter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) instead.

Comment: Thanks for this reference. This helps. I've edited my question above to reflect the addition of the transaction method.

Comment: Now return the promise returned from runTransaction.  This is standard requirement for background functions.  It's required for all functions and not at all unique to transactions.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Answer (score 0):

Here's one potential solution.  You could *record* the votes using sharding, but then use cloud functions to aggregate the shard totals and update your counter.  That should reduce the number of document reads and therefore your Firestore bill.

Tutorial here: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-cloud-functions-data-aggregation/