# How to: Rating System with Firestore Function?

Tags: android, function, google-cloud-firestore, cloud, counter

I am creating a rating system for my App. I have two collections.
Ratings and Items.

Every time a user rates an item, It goes inside the Ratings.
(e.g rating: 1)

What I want to do is every time someone rates an item, a cloud function will trigger that will get all the ratings and put it in the Items.
(e.g total_ratings: 400)

I've read something that I need to use Sharded Counter to have it right because there is a limit in writing in one document.

[Increment counter with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016210/increment-counter-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase)

But I've got no knowledge in node.js or how this Sharded Counter works. I can't understand how it works.

Can someone please help me how to do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: The documentation has a page showing how to implement distributed counters: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters. If you're having trouble implementing that, show the minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck.

Comment: Hey, were you able to build a function for this?